# como leer un archivo txt en java y pasarlo a una matriz

Tags: java, string, matrices

tengo el siguiente código en java para leer un archivo txt

```
                      // recibe la dirección del archivo
public String leerTxt (String direccion){ 
      String texto="";
      try {
        BufferedReader bf= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(direccion));
        String temp="";
        String bfRead;
        while ((bfRead = bf.readLine()) != null){ // se hace el ciclo, mientras bfRead tenga datos
          temp=temp+bfRead;// guardado del texto de archivo
        }
        texto= temp;
        }
      catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("no se encontro archivo");
        }
      return texto;
}
```

mi pregunta es: como podría hacer una matriz con cada uno de los caracteres del txt, osea que si por ejemplo tengo un archivo con un hello world, la h quede en la posición 0,0 de la matriz, la e en la posicion 0,1, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existen varias formas, una de ellas podrá ser con ciclos:

```
char[] mat=new char[texto.lenght]
for(int i=0;i<texto.lenght;i++){
   mat[i]=texto.substring(i,i+1);
}
```